# Combine two handlers into one Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, handler

In an earlier question I posted, someone mentioned that I can combine two handlers together to save myself from typing code twice. The two click handlers I have below do duplicate code, but I'm not sure how to organize them into one function so that when I click the left arrow button, the function knows I clicked the left button and responds accordingly, and likewise with the right arrow button. I imagine that I'll have an if statement but do I need to have each button run an argument through the function? How do I do that?

The code below loops through a list of images in the HTML and finds the appropriate image to place on the lightbox. I can go through the list from top to bottom and bottom to top. I can also move from the first child to the last child and vice versa. I'm just not sure if these two can be combined together or not.

These buttons are programmatically appended to the overlay.

```
var $arrowLeft = $('<button id="left" class="arrow">&lsaquo;</button>');
var $arrowRight = $('<button id="right" class="arrow">&rsaquo;</button>');
```

Left and right arrow handlers:

```
//When left arrow is clicked
$arrowLeft.click(function() {
    $('#imageGallery li a img').each(function() {
        var galleryImage = $(this);
        if (galleryImage.attr('src') === $image.attr('src')) {
            var li = galleryImage.closest('li');
            if (li.is(':first-child')) {
                var gallery = li.parent();
                var lastLi = gallery.children(':last-child');
                var anchor = lastLi.children('a');
                var image = anchor.children('img');
                $image.attr('src', image.attr('src'));
            } else {
                var prevLi = li.prev();
                var anchor = prevLi.children('a');
                var image = anchor.children('img');
                $image.attr('src', image.attr('src'));
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
});

//When right arrow is clicked
$arrowRight.click(function() {
    $('#imageGallery li a img').each(function() {
        var galleryImage = $(this);
        if (galleryImage.attr('src') === $image.attr('src')) {
            var li = galleryImage.closest('li');
            if (li.is(':last-child')) {
                var gallery = li.parent();
                var firstLi = gallery.children(':first-child');
                var anchor = firstLi.children('a');
                var image = anchor.children('img');
                $image.attr('src', image.attr('src'));
            } else {
                var nextLi = li.next();
                var anchor = nextLi.children('a');
                var image = anchor.children('img');
                $image.attr('src', image.attr('src'));
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <h1>Image Gallery</h1>
    <ul id="imageGallery">
        <li><a href="images/refferal_machine.png"><img src="images/refferal_machine.png" width="100" alt="Refferal Machine By Matthew Spiel"></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/space-juice.png"><img src="images/space-juice.png" width="100" alt="Space Juice by Mat Helme"></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/education.png"><img src="images/education.png" width="100" alt="Education by Chris Michel"></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/copy_mcrepeatsalot.png"><img src="images/copy_mcrepeatsalot.png" width="100" alt="Wanted: Copy McRepeatsalot by Chris Michel"></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/sebastian.png"><img src="images/sebastian.png" width="100" alt="Sebastian by Mat Helme"></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/skill-polish.png"><img src="images/skill-polish.png" width="100" alt="Skill Polish by Chris Michel"></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/chuck.png"><img src="images/chuck.png" width="100" alt="Chuck by Mat Helme"></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/library.png"><img src="images/library.png" width="100" alt="Library by Tyson Rosage"></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/boat.png"><img src="images/boat.png" width="100" alt="Boat by Griffin Moore"></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/illustrator_foundations.png"><img src="images/illustrator_foundations.png" width="100" alt="Illustrator Foundations by Matthew Spiel"></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/treehouse_shop.jpg"><img src="images/treehouse_shop.jpg" width="100" alt="Treehouse Shop by Eric Smith"></a></li>
    </ul>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: where are the left and right buttons in your markup? You can bind your handler on the generic element and then with event delegation use `e.target` to find which button was clicked.

Comment: They are programmatically added to the overlay. I can post them if need be.

Comment: please post it with html code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may either use (as already answered) the target to determine the button.
You may also have two handlers which call the same function, I made an example to explain what I mean, I hope you understand the principle (Did not test it)

```
//When left arrow is clicked
$arrowLeft.click(function() {
    moveImages(true);
});

//When right arrow is clicked
$arrowRight.click(function() {
    moveImages(false);
});

function moveImages(topToBottom) {
    var ttb = ':last-child';
    if(topToBottom) {
        ttb = ':first-child';
    }

        $('#imageGallery li a img').each(function() {
        var galleryImage = $(this);
        if (galleryImage.attr('src') === $image.attr('src')) {
            var li = galleryImage.closest('li');
            if (li.is(ttb)) {
                var gallery = li.parent();
                var aLi = gallery.children(ttb);
                var anchor = aLi.children('a');
                var image = anchor.children('img');
                $image.attr('src', image.attr('src'));
            } else {
                var theLi;
                if(topToBottom) {
                    theLi = li.next();
                } else {
                    theLi  = li.prev();
                }
                var anchor = theLi.children('a');
                var image = anchor.children('img');
                $image.attr('src', image.attr('src'));
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: You could also do `$arrowLeft.add($arrowRight).on('click', moveImages)` and within `moveImages` see what's the id (`this.id)`of the clicked element.

Comment: Thanks everyone for their examples. I liked yours, @Xavjer, because I can also implement this same example in another js app I've been tinkering with. I changed a few things, but they are, in the grand scheme of things, very minor from what you've posted here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your callback have event parameter which contains which key has been pressed.

```
$('a').mousedown(function(f) {
   if (f.which == 0) {
       alert('left button')
   }
   else if(f.which == 2) {
       alert("right click");
   }
})​
```

According to W3C its values should be:

Left button – 0
Middle button – 1
Right button – 2

Answer (score 0):

Use `e.target` to find out which button was clicked.

Something along these lines:

```
$('a.arrows').on('click', function(e) {
    // ... your common variables here
    if(e.target.id === 'leftArrow') {
        // ... your logic for left arrow
    } else {
        // ... your logic for right arrw
    }
});
```

Where `arrows` is a class that you could put on your arrow buttons. Alternatively, you could bind your click handler to a parent element. Logic remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : You can bind click event handler using id selector as shown below. You can identify the clicked button whether it is left or right using id of the button and create logic accordingly.

```
$(document).on('click','#left, #right' ,function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var liCheck = ':first-child';
    var childCheck = ':last-child';

    //for right button swap the child and li check
    if(id == 'right')
    {
      childCheck = ':first-child';
      liCheck = ':last-child';
    }

    $('#imageGallery li a img').each(function() {
        var galleryImage = $(this);
        if (galleryImage.attr('src') === $image.attr('src')) {
            var li = galleryImage.closest('li');
            if (li.is(liCheck)) {
                var gallery = li.parent();
                var childLi = gallery.children(childCheck);
                var anchor = childLi.children('a');
                var image = anchor.children('img');
                $image.attr('src', image.attr('src'));
            } else {
                var childLi = li.prev();
                //for right button update child li
                if(id == 'right')
                {
                  childLi = li.next();
                }
                var anchor = childLi.children('a');
                var image = anchor.children('img');
                $image.attr('src', image.attr('src'));
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Missing a `,` => `'#left #right'` and `$(this).attr('id')` could simply be `this.id`